# Cookie Decryption / STS SSO with 3rd Party Application

Tags: .net, security, cookies, token, wif

I have a .NET 4.0 SSO application running through an STS I built. The SSO works great between the STS, RP, and my SharePoint Application. I have a 3rd party system I need to integrate with my STS. This will be hosted on the same domain as the other applications. The easiest route I would think would be to setup the application as a relying party to the STS. However the application is not a .NET application. This application is written in java and our team has very little control. Is there a way to give them the key used to generate the cookie so they can decrypt it? If the 3rd party can get the username, they would authenticate on that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend doing that -

a) you would need to have that cookie - meaning you need to first log into a WS-Fed RP and then to you Java app

b) encryption and encoding of the session cookie is proprietary - you would need to reverse engineer that. Also no guarantees that the internals might change in a service release.

I'd rather investigate in a library that understands SAML tokens and do the WS-Fed request manually.